# Using reactJS is there a way to create "n" number of divs/html tags with different information on them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I'm building this site and right now i have 4 divs that do basically the same thing, but theyre being copy and pasted 4 times and just like 4 bits of information are being changed from them. is there any way using react that i can make it so its only one div and a function handles the different parameters needed for the divs? here is is a quick example.

quickExample.jsx

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";

function test(props) {
    animalAmount = useRef(20);
    return (
        <div>
            <div id='turtle-id'>
                <h1>I like turtles!</h1>
                <p>there are {animalAmount.current} turtles in my house!</p>
                <button>Click me!</button>
            </div>
            <div id='dog-id'>
                <h1>I like dogs!</h1>
                <p>there are {animalAmount.current} dogs in my house!</p>
                <button>Click me!</button>
            </div>
            <div id='fish-id'>
                <h1>I like fish!</h1>
                <p>there are {animalAmount.current} fish in my house!</p>
                <button>Click me!</button>
            </div>
            <div id='hippo-id'>
                <h1>I like hippos!</h1>
                <p>there are {animalAmount.current} hippos in my house!</p>
                <button>Click me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default test;
```

for specific reasons I cant just create a parent component and call it there and duplicate it four times, it needs to be done in this component if possible.

Comment: What's in `props`? Can you add your animals to an array of objects and then iterate over that array creating new `<Animal>` components from the objects. FYI `test` should be `Test` (PascalCase for React components). You also already have a parent component. Where are you storing state?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with your data, and then use `map` to print the divs:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 'turtle-id',
    title: 'I like turtles',
    text: '...',
    // rest of needed data
  }, {
    // ...
  }
];

return (
  data.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item.id} id={item.id}>
         <h1>{item.title}</h1>
         <p>{item.text}</p>
         <button>Click me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects outside of component and loop through them. Something like this.

```
const animals = [{
 id: "turtle-id",
 title: "I like turtles!",
 defineText: (value) => `there are ${value} turtles in my house!`
}, ....]
```

and then in your component's return, you can do something like this.

```
...
return (
    <div>
      {animals.map((animal) => {
        return (
          <div key={animal.id} id={animal.id}>
            <h1>{animal.title}</h1>
            <p>{animal.defineText(animalAmount.current)}</p>
            <button>Click me!</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a set of data describing the animals and set your state with it.
2. Shift your animal containers into a new component (`Animal`).
3. `map` over the animals state to create a series of Animals.
4. When a button is clicked update the count value of that animal.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in some data
function Animals({ data }) {

  // Initialise state with the data
  const [ animals, setAnimals ] = useState(data);

  // Copy the state, find the name of the
  // animal we're updating the count for from
  // the container's dataset, find the index of the
  // animal object in state, update its count value
  // and the update the state
  function handleCount(e) {
    const copy = [...animals];
    const { name } = e.target.closest('.animal').dataset;
    const index = copy.findIndex(obj => obj.name === name);
    ++copy[index].count;
    setAnimals(copy);
  }

  // `map` over the animals state
  // an return an array of Animal components
  return animals.map(animal => {
    return (
      <Animal
        animal={animal}
        handleCount={handleCount}
      />
    );
  });

}

// Animal component
function Animal({ animal, handleCount }) {
  return (
    <div className="animal" data-name={animal.name}>
      <h1>I like {animal.plural}!</h1>
      <p>There are {animal.count} {animal.plural} in my house!</p>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const data = [
  { name: 'turtle', plural: 'turtles', count: 0 },
  { name: 'dog', plural: 'dogs', count: 0 },
  { name: 'fish', plural: 'fish', count: 0 },
  { name: 'hippo', plural: 'hippos', count: 0 }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Animals data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```